# jQuery mobile is messing with my links

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using using [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). Testing my web page on iPhone.

Here is the issue:

I am on `http://www.mywebsite.com/here.html` and I have an anchor on that page that points to

`href="http://www.mywebsite.com/some/folder/there.html"`, I'm navigated to

`http://www.mywebsite.com/here.html#/some/folder/there.html`

If I remove jQuery mobile js file, everything works as expected. So it looks like jQuery mobile is intercepting my 'tap' event and modifies url to the link. Weird.  Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [this is done on purpose](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/pages/page-links.html) to help you with animated page transitions and such.

I can turn it off by adding this attribute to the anchor `data-ajax="false"`

Comment: Fantastic answer! I was just about to ask the same question until I stumbled upon this answer. Much appreciated!